# DB2 FUNCTION TEST ERROR

Tags: db2

HOW to resolve this problem ? :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "BADIL_PROD"."FCT_UPDATE_POINTAGE" (id_projet in NUMBER) 
return NUMBER 
is

  Results NUMBER;
  CURSOR cur_update  IS
          SELECT distinct t.ID_TACHE,t.id_collaborateur,t.id_ref_rubrique_activite
          FROM TACHES t
          where t.ID_PROJET =id_projet ;


begin

dbms_output.enable(200000);
  FOR cur in cur_update
    LOOP
     BEGIN

 dbms_output.put_line(cur.ID_TACHE || '--' || cur.ID_COLLABORATEUR || '--' || cur.ID_REF_RUBRIQUE_ACTIVITE);
 UPDATE POINTAGES p SET p.ID_TACHE_INCIDENT = cur.ID_TACHE
 where p.id_projet_tma=id_projet
 and p.ID_COLLABORATEUR = cur.ID_COLLABORATEUR
 AND p.ID_REF_RUBRIQUE_ACTIVITE = cur.ID_REF_RUBRIQUE_ACTIVITE;

  END;
END LOOP;

  results:=0;
  return(results);

end fct_update_pointage;
```

So when I want to test this function I get this error in data studio :

> (specific name "FCT_UPDATE_POINTAGE") attempted to modify data but was
>   not defined as MODIFIES SQL DATA.. SQLCODE=-577,

Comment: You seem to be using PL/SQL for your function; have you enabled Oracle compatibility in your database?

Comment: yes i did ......

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with DB2 V11 on Linux:

```
db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=830
db2stop
db2start
db2 create database mydb
db2 connect to mydb
db2 "create table taches(....)"
db2 "create table pointages(...)"
db2 -tvf FCT_UPDATE_POINTAGE.sql
```

(where FCT_UPDATE_POINTAGE.sql contains your function definition )

However, note the documented restriction in the documentation "Compiled SQL functions (including PL/SQL functions) that MODIFY SQL DATA can only be used as the only element on the right side of an assignment statement that is within a compound SQL (compiled) statement."

DB2 Version 9.7 allowed the "modifies sql data" clause when defining PL/SQL user defined functions, but IBM removed that ability at DB2 Version 10.1 and higher.  Maybe you need to convert to an sproc.

Comment: i had no problem when creating the function, but when i want to execute it in a select query : 
SELECT FCT_UPDATE_POINTAGE(arg) from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1; 
i get this error :
(specific name "FCT_UPDATE_POINTAGE") attempted to modify data but was not defined as MODIFIES SQL DATA.. SQLCODE=-577,